# In div style="overflow:auto" not working properly in IE 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a table with a single row and 2 tds.

In each td, I am using a div and have set overflow to auto. My code is working fine in chrome, firefox and IE 8,9,10 but not working properly in IE 11.

In the correct case, the scroll bar appears and I can scroll down but in IE 11 no scroll bar appears.

This is the part of the code in which the problem lies.

Here's the the link to the code I have written.
jsfiddle.net/XrH7f/

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML Transitional//EN">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-874">

<html>
<head><style>
table
{
    border-top-color: #d3dfe2;
    border-right-color: #d3dfe2;
    border-bottom-color: #d3dfe2;
    border-left-color: #d3dfe2;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-image-outset: 0;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
}
table td
{
    border-top-color: #d3dfe2;
    border-right-color: #d3dfe2;
    border-bottom-color: #d3dfe2;
    border-left-color: #d3dfe2;
    border-top-width: 1px;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-left-width: 1px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-left-style: solid;
    border-image-source: none;
    border-image-slice: 100%;
    border-image-width: 1;
    border-image-outset: 0;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
}
td
{
    color: #003366;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

</style></head>
<body text="#000000" topmargin="0" leftmargin="1" bgcolor="#ffffff"><form name="form1" action="page2.jsp" method="POST">

<table width="100%" align="center" bordercolor="#d3dfe2" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">

 <tbody>
  <tr bgcolor="#ecfefe">


   <td width="17%" height="100" align="right" valign="middle">

    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;">

                                 Select Make:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;ALL: <input name="allMake" onclick="selectallMe();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="ALL" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />


                                 Abcdef         <input name="Make" onclick="selectAllMake();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="BBDC           " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 Abcdef         <input name="Make" onclick="selectAllMake();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="MBCL           " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 Abcdef         <input name="Make" onclick="selectAllMake();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="LIQUIDITY      " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 Abcdefghijkl         <input name="Make" onclick="selectAllMake();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="TPH            " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 Abcdef         <input name="Make" onclick="selectAllMake();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="CGCSL          " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 Abcdef         <input name="Make" onclick="selectAllMake();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="MB             " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 Abcdef         <input name="Make" onclick="selectAllMake();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="CG             " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />
>

   </td>


   <td width="17%" height="100" align="right" valign="middle">

    <!-- Here we will place the check Boxes of "Select Make" and "Select Condition"  -->

    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;">

                                Select Condition:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ALL: <input name="allCondition" onclick="selectAllCn();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="ALL" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 1<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="DEMO" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 2<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="NEW " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 3<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="SOLD" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 4<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="SR  " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 5<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="WH  " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 6<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="VQC " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 7<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="PHWH" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 8<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="PHSR" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 9<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="DST " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 10<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="DIS " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 11<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="DB  " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 12<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="DST2" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 13<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="FLET" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

                                 14<input name="Condition" onclick="selectAllCondition();" onchange="changeVisiblityVehicle()" type="checkbox" checked="" value="MS  " />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />

    </div>

   </td>

  </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>

</form></body></html>
```

Comment: It works fine with me (IE 10)!

Comment: Aside, but you can eliminate a whole bunch of properties by using the shorthand property: `border: 1px solid #d3dfe2`.

Comment: @steveax thx for the tip. I am already using the same format you told. I copied the code from view source, and it subdivides the property in these divisions. Thx for the advice though.

Comment: @AdamZapp Then why is it not showing in IE 11

Comment: I don't have/use IE 11 but, you can force the div to show the scroll bar using `overflow-y: scroll;` instead of `overflow: auto;`

Comment: @AdamZapp Tried that but it didn't work. The scroll bar appears but it doesn't moves the list down. I have fixed all the faults while moving to IE 10,11 but I am stuck at this one...

Answer (score 2):

Ahhh. Finally got the answer after some R&D. The height of the div tag when specified in % creates a problem. changed the height of the 1st div from 100% to 100px and volla !!!!! Got the Fix. Thanks for the help guys.

Also set the vlign attribute of the 1st td to top from middle.

Comment: As a good habit, don't use inline css or you will encounter such probllem that can't be solved by changing css